# Error while importing scipy.spatial.distance in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-spatial

While I am running this code in ubuntu 14.04, I want to calculate the cosine distance of an array with scipy.spatial.distance. But it is throwing me an error in importing scipy.spatial.distance.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist


x=np.array([[[-0.22008298,  0.28819615,  0.09895946,  0.16789497,  0.02379252,
   -0.25700486,  0.1628186,   0.12296761,  0.01750283]],

 [[ 0.29891527,  0.17249978, -0.10084602, -0.16522293,  0.06811064,
    0.07434326, -0.19697316, -0.22199543,  0.07647966]],

 [[-0.04112297,  0.13392878, -0.06575392,  0.0893533,   0.22577047,
    0.00289264,  0.09996213,  0.17324321,  0.08673526]]])


B =x.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,x.shape[0])
print(B.shape) 
print (B.ndim)
#array.astype(int)
print(B)
y=1-(pdist(B, metric='cosine'))
print(y)
```

It is throwing this error,

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cos1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    from .kdtree import *
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 8, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .compressed import _cs_matrix
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._util import _prune_array
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py", line 9, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 37, in <module>
    import dis
  File "/home/mayesha/dis.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
  File "/home/mayesha/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 119, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._util import _asarray_validated
ImportError: cannot import name _asarray_validated
```

I am using  virtual environment with pip.
Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with scipy 1.0.1 and numpy 1.14.3. Is your error reproducible with the posted code after a restart?

Comment: It is throwing the same error.

Comment: Then you might want to edit your question and add more information about your environment, how you run your code.

Comment: Can you refer me a link from which I can install scipy? because I have reinstall it but it is throwing me the same the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install -U scipy
```

This will solve your issue. I have tried and it did for me. You might get an error that scikit-learn is not installed properly. If you get that error, you can first run:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

and then rerun the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Installing package *sklearn* solved my problem.